# Flutter: When I debug my App, my App creates this files

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-plugin

My App have a Problem so I Need to do flutter clean before I can debug my app.

So I do flutter clean and after that flutter run in my Terminal.

Then my App debug. After that flutter creates a new build folder, new .flutter-plugins and .flutter-plugins-dependencies.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now I think the problem is not there but sometimes it creates the files.

Can I delete the files? And how can I fix it?

PS: I have the newest version of flutter and Xcode. And I work with VSCode and I work on a MacBook with the newest Version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this, but in one case I tried adding resource permission from info.plist(I messed with internal storage permission), I noticed similar behaviour.